# Access VPN connection on guest Virtual PC from Host OS

Tags: windows, 64-bit, vpn, virtual-pc, cisco

I am running as my Host OS - Win 7 x64 and running an instance of Virtual PC XP. I am running the Cisco ISPec VPN Client on the Guest XP VPC OS and can successfully connect to my company's corporate network.

I cannot run the Cisco IPSec client sw on the Host, because it is 64-bit, Cisco doesn't support 64-bit on its IPSec client products and I don't have alot of choices at the moment in terms of moving to Cisco's SSL VPN client (AnyConnect).

The XP VPC Guest OS is not using the NAT network adapter, but the physical adapter of the machine.

I can ping the Host from the Guest OS and vice versa when Cisco Client is not running on the XP VPC guest OS.

Couple of problems:

1. When the Cisco client is running and connected the guest OS cannot see the Host any longer.
2. I would like to be able to access the VPN from the Host when the XP VPC guest is connected to VPN.

For #2, I have tried at least one technique, described: xenomorph.net/use-cisco-vpn-under-vista-x64/

This technique turns on ICS on the Cisco pseudo network adapter.

I could not get this to work. I may have followed the instructions incorrectly, however.

I have also looked at: http://www.pringle.net.nz/blog/PermaLink,guid,12ee0de7-f998-4084-8b06-537b3dbd5d9a.aspx

... which involves using a Loopback adapter and bridging between the host and guest OS. I have not followed this because the instructions are not completely clear.

Lastly, I have seen references on the net regarding a x64 build of OpenVPN, but I am hesitant to go in that direction.

Can anyone steer me in the correct direction regarding what to do?

Answer (score -1):

actually cisco has cisco vpn client for windows 7 64 bit  ,you can find it on 4shared.com ,but still cisco does not have client for windows 8